# Convert ISO 8601 Date to a Standard String Format

Tags: java, jodatime, iso8601

I am trying to convert a valid [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string to a consistent format so that sort and search using simple lexicographical order is possible.

My application could receive a date/time in any of the following formats, for example:

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17.000+00:00
2015-02-05T02:05:17+00:00
2015-02-05T02:05:17Z
```

These all represent the same date/time and I would like to convert them all to a canonical form for storage, say:

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17.000Z
```

My first thought was to just parse them using a technique from [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date), and then convert back to the desired string, but this breaks down when dealing with less precise date/times, for example:

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17Z
2015-02-05T02:05Z
2015-02-05Z
2015-02Z
2015Z
```

The imprecision of these times should be preserved. They should not be converted to:

```
2015-02-05T00:00:00.000Z
```

I've looked Java 8 and Joda-Time, but they seem to want to treat everything as specific points in time, and can't model the imprecise nature or partial dates/times.

UPDATE:

Using Java 8, I can do:

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-02-05T02:05:17+00:00");
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

which gives me:

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17Z
```

which is what I want, but:

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-02-05T02:05:17.000+00:00");
System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

also gives me:

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17Z
```

Notice that java has thrown away the millisecond precision. Specifying 000 is treated the same as not specifying anything, which doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: `2015-02-05T02:05:17+0000` is not a valid ISO date.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that +0000 is a valid offset. Do you have a better reference?

Comment: I dont think there is a single object which can hold a date with the restrictions you have defined (i.e. partial precision). So your best bet is to use your own representation.

Comment: @JamesScriven, if WP says that then it is wrong. You have either provide all parts in extended format or in standard format but not in a mixed fashion. See my [comment](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/pull/94#issuecomment-70377338) on Jersey about this. I can cite the chapter of ISO 8601 if you like.

Comment: @Michael-O The distinction between basic and extended notation was not clear in my head. I've updated the question to remove the bad examples. Thanks.

Comment: You can store the LocalDateTime and the precision as two fields.  This will keep all the information you need.  There is not a single built in type which will do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

In Java 8, you can use [LocalDate.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) or [LocalDateTime.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) on a `String` without providing it with a pattern, if the String is in **ISO 8601** format.

> `parse()`,
>   Obtains an instance of LocalDate from a text string such as 2007-12-03.
>   The string must represent a valid date and is parsed using
>   DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.

and,

> `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`,
>   This returns an immutable formatter capable of formatting and parsing
>   the ISO 8601

for example,

```
String strDate = "2015-08-04";
LocalDate aLD = LocalDate.parse(strDate);
System.out.println("Date: " + aLD);

String strDatewithTime = "2015-08-04T10:11:30";
LocalDateTime aLDT = LocalDateTime.parse(strDatewithTime);
System.out.println("Date with Time: " + aLDT);
```

*gives,*

```
Date: 2015-08-04
Date with Time: 2015-08-04T10:11:30
```

**Update:**

your date, i.e `"2015-02-05T02:05:17.000+00:00"` would only throw zeros away when
they are all zeros, if the value of nano seconds is other than zeros then it will display just fine, however, if you want to display zeros too then you can simply add `if/else` block and append zeros to your date `if` your nano-of-seconds are zeros (`yourdate.getNano()==0`), `else` print it as it is,

```
String dateTimestr = "2015-02-05T02:05:17.000+00:00";

OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimestr);

if ((dateTime.getNano() == 0) && (dateTimestr.length() > 25 ))
    System.out.println(dateTime.toLocalDateTime() + ".000Z");

else
    System.out.println(dateTime.toString());
```

*will give,*

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17.000Z
```

changing your date to,

```
String dateTimestr = "2015-02-05T02:05:17+00:00";
```

*gives,*

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17Z
```

changing date to,

```
String dateTimestr = "2015-02-05T02:05:17.100+00:00";
```

*gives,*

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17.100Z
```

changing it to,

```
String dateTimestr = "2015-02-05T02:05:17Z";
```

*gives,*

```
2015-02-05T02:05:17Z
```

Comment: This is very useful, but please see my update for why it doesn't quite work.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this addresses the issue of maintaining precision (and lack of precision)

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand that the **preservation of precision can only happen in textual space but not in value space**. So a different degree of precision can be expressed in a textual way (see your input), but not in the value object (here of type `OffsetDateTime`). Latter only stores the date-time-value but not any extra precision information. If you really want to achieve this goal then you have no other choice than to write your own class as wrapper around an `OffsetDateTime` and the precision (expressed as `ChronoUnit`-enum).

Otherwise, if you always want to preserve the precision in milliseconds for your output then you should not use the `toString()`-method but a dedicated formatter. In Java-8 this would be like:

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2015-02-05T02:05:17+00:00");
String dateTimeWithMilliSecondPrecision = 
  odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSxxx"));
System.out.println(dateTimeWithMilliSecondPrecision);
// output: 2015-02-05T02:05:17.000+00:00
```