# Parse date-only value in ISO 8601 format in java.time (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: java, java-time, iso8601

How do I parse YYYY-MM-DD dates in modern Java?

I have a Java String of a standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date in the YYYY-MM-DD format, such as `2016-03-21`.

How can I parse this into the modern Date-Time types in Java, the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes?

*Note: This is intended to be a canonical post for a common question.*

Comment: I posted this Question and Answer as a reference for this specific case that requires no formatting pattern to be defined. Comes up frequently as a part of other Questions such as [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39706433/642706).

Comment: Is this intended to be a canonical question? If so, it's worth noting that so that the rest of us don't nuke it from orbit.

Comment: @chrylis Yes, so intended. How do you suggest I note it as such?

Comment: How about this question @Basil http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43802/how-to-convert-a-date-string-to-a-date-or-calendar-object? Your answer there covers this case also.

Comment: @MarcB and Tunaki: Both are referring to the old date packages, not Java 8.

Comment: @chrylis Top answer yes, but not Basil's one http://stackoverflow.com/a/33405474/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki Basil's answer doesn't actually answer that question as posed, which is asking about `Date` and `Calendar`.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think it'd may be better to edit [that canonical](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4216767/1743880) with this special case. Because there are `LocalDateTime.parse` and `ZonedDateTime.parse` without formatter as well. (Ah, I found [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352493/convert-iso-8601-date-to-a-standard-string-format) as well).

Comment: @Tunaki The posts you linked are so broad, so long, address so many issues including some historic issues such as Joda-Time and the legacy date-time classes, that is overkill for such a simple and *common* question of “How do I parse YYYY-MM-DD dates in modern Java?”. And so I wrote this Question and Answer.

Comment: The [supposed duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4216745/642706) is *not* a duplicate. That Question asks about an input string in the format “January 2, 2010” with English words. This Question here is about standard ISO 8601 format, all digits and hyphens, no English words. Furthermore, the Answers for that other Question go on to discuss the complexities of formatting pattern codes which are not at all required in this common case of ISO 8601 strings being discussed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `LocalDate.parse`

The [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes can parse [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings directly, with no need to specify a formatting pattern.

For a date-only value, without a time of day or time zone, use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("2016-03-21");
```

Comment: What if you can't guarantee whether the parsed value will have the time/timezone part or not? There doesn't seem to be a parse() method that will correctly parse both "YYYY-MM-DD" and "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM+ZZ:VV" for instance. Both of them are valid ISO8601 dates.

Comment: @Tiago  No, there is not a single way to parse two such *very* different inputs, where one represents a date and the other represents a moment. You could easily check the length of the input to know which is which and choose an appropriate parsing approach.