# Convert a string to date for database

Tags: java, database, date

I am trying to convert a string into a date type, so I can save the current time someone last logged in, into my database. The field in the database takes the date type only and not a string representation of it.

Here is my code for getting the current date and formatting it:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
carrier.setLastUpdateDate(dateFormat.format(date));
```

---

Error:

**incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Date**

Comment: The only way for *that* code to fail to compile with *that* error message, is for parameter to `setLastUpdateDate` to be a `Date`. Since `format` returns a `String`, you'd get that exact compilation error. If parameter to `setLastUpdateDate` is a `Date`, why do anything with `SimpleDateFormat`? Use do `carrier.setLastUpdateDate(new Date());`

Comment: See: [Parse date-only value in ISO 8601 format in java.time (YYYY-MM-DD)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39706895/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Parse, not format

The `format` command generates a string, whereas you are trying to do the opposite, parse a String. So you should have called `parse`.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Another problem: You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Avoid `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and others not in the java.time package.

## Date-only, not date-time

Another problem: You are using a date-time class to represent a date-only value.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### ISO 8601

No need to specify a parsing pattern. Your input happens to be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The java.time classes use standard formats by default when parsing and generating strings.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017-01-23" ) ;
```

## Use objects with database, not strings

Another problem: You are using strings to communicate with your database rather than appropriate data types (objects).

Pass the java.time objects to your database directly with a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2. Call `PreparedStatement::setObject`.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ ( when_ ) VALUES ( ? ) ; " ;
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( sql ) ;
ps.setObject( 1 , ld ) ;  // Pass the java.time object directly.
```

Going the other direction, use `ResultSet::getObject`.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

> The field in the database takes the **date** type only and not a **string**
>   representation of it.

Your error is clear, you can't set a String in a date type, so instead of convert the date to string set the date like this :

```
carrier.setLastUpdateDate(new Date());
```

Comment: I wonder why this answer was down-voted. I obviously [agree with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133681/convert-a-string-to-date-for-database#comment79229851_46133681). YCF_L, maybe you need to explain more clear, e.g. something like I did in that comment? +1 from me.

Comment: thank you @Andreas i appreciate your fair action yes this is true of what you said in your comment

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy");
Date d=new Date();
String date1 = df.format(d);
java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
System.out.println(date1);
System.out.println(df.format(date2));
```